# React app production build shows js errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, deployment, react-scripts

I've created a client react application using `create-react-app`. It talks to a node server running an express api. In development everything is working great and was getting ready to deploy.

When running `npm run build` I get no errors whatsoever either, everything seems to be working great. When build finishes it suggest to run `serve -s build` , I do this and navigate to my localhost:5000, the first console.logs from my app show up but then suddenly i throws a seemingly simple javascript error:

```
TypeError: "e.forEach is not a function"
    me InboundTab.js:27
    me InboundTab.js:36
    React 7
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.production.min.js:270
    React 5
    getArrivals ArrivalState.js:39
    l runtime.js:45
    _invoke runtime.js:264
    t runtime.js:98
    l runtime.js:45
    t runtime.js:137
    t runtime.js:147
react-dom.production.min.js:4636:12
    React 5
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.production.min.js:270
    React 4
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.production.min.js:270
    React 5
    getArrivals ArrivalState.js:39
    l runtime.js:45
    _invoke runtime.js:264
    t runtime.js:98
    l runtime.js:45
    t runtime.js:137
    t runtime.js:147
```

I've been looking all over the internet but can't find any clues on what's going on here. Most sites talk about errors during the build process or a site not showing at all but this is neither. Googling the error seems to say this is some ES6 issue, but I'm running firefox 73 so I'd expect no issues on that front.

As extra info this is my first time trying to deploy react. Funny enough I'd only done small projects so far running locally so I am pretty sure I'm missing something obvious in the build process.

Any help, tips on where to loop will be most appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. I guess I just needed to re-read this error with the nice syntax highlight because the filename and line location took me to the right place.

On my client's api calls I set up the server url as:

```
const API_SERVER =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
    ? "http://localhost:4200"
    : "http://example.com";
```

but my example.com isn't setup yet so the error came from not being able to reach the server. Changing the example.com to localhost and re-building made things work.